# React Component with Dynamic Tag Name Not Rendered

Tags: reactjs

I have a working Component called "Button" and this Component uses it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import Button from './Boxes/Button'

class AutoGraph extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.placed = {
      components: [
        {
          type: 'Button',
          x: 10,
          y: 10
        }
      ]
    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
        <svg width={this.windowWidth} height={this.windowHeight}>

        <g id="component-layer">{this.placed.components.map((item, i) => {
          return React.createElement(item.type, {
            key: i,
            x: item.x,
            y: item.y
          })
        })}
          <Button x="150" y="20"/>
        </g>

      </svg>
    )
  }
}

export default AutoGraph
```

The dynamically created Button just renders as <Button x="10" y="10"/> but the hard coded Button component directly after it renders correctly. How do I get my dynamically created Button to render using my Button component code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are used for built-in types (`div`, `a`, etc). Functions and classes denote custom components. If you want to render your custom component you have to pass that class/function:

Change

```
 type: 'Button',
```

to

```
 type: Button,
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! How can I convert the string to the class? I want to retrieve the Button component from the string 'Button' but eval('Button') is not working.

Comment: You should build a lookup table for the components that you want to load dynamically. E.g. `const components = {Button};` (which is equivalent to `{Button: Button}`) and then later you can do `React.createElement(components[this.place.type], ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference the component itself, not the string with its name:

```
{
   type: Button, // not a string
   x: 10,
   y: 10
}
```